# How to install eCommerce module in OpenErp 7

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I'm using OpenERP 7 from last 8 months.Today I came across eCommerce module in www.odoo.com. After that I tried to search eCommerce module in my OpenERP I couldn't find. Can any one please tell me how can I install eCommerce in my existing OpenERP. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such module in openerp 7, you have to get it from repository and install (But check for dependencies, as it may depend on modules that also not included in openerp 7).
Here is [link for the module's folder in repository](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/8.0/addons/website_sale).